# Android APP crash on getLastKnownLocation()

Tags: java, android, geolocation, position

I'm developing an Android app which achieve the position through NETWORK_PROVIDER, but I have problems on executing it on Android 7 (while it correctly works on previous versions). This is the code:

```
LocationManager posM;
double latitude;
double longitude;

List<Address> addresses = null;

try {
    posM =  (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location = posM.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();

    Geocoder geocoder;

    geocoder = new Geocoder(Activity1.this, Locale.getDefault());

    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I don't know why it crashes on Android 7... Thank you for help

Comment: Please add the stack trace

Comment: show error stacktrace

Comment: Excuse me, how can I get error stacktrace on phone?

Comment: can you post your crash log here

Comment: you get it in android studio in the android monitor at the bottom

Comment: "while it correctly works on previous versions" -- no, it does not. It happened to work in your limited testing. But, as Gabe points out, `getLastKnownLocation()` returns `null` a lot, and you need to be able to deal with that. [The documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) describes this process. Only use `getLastKnownLocation()` as an optimization, not your primary way of getting the location.

Answer (score 1):

Because `getLastKnownLocation` returns null most of the time.  The system generally doesn't know your `location`.  Use `requestLocationUpdates` or `requestSingleUpdate` to turn on the `location` detection and get the actual location.

Comment: Thank you, but why does this happen only on Android 7? It perfectly works on 5...

Comment: It will succeed or fail depending on if the system has a location it already knows and that isn't stale, on any OS.  The fact you're seeing it on 7 and not 5 is a coincidence.  Perhaps you have another app that is using location on your 5 device and not your 7.  Or perhaps the caching code hanged a bit.  But it can and will happen on any OS version.  getLastKnownLocation can be used as an optimization, but never relied upon.